# How to remove duplicate from an array using vb script without using dictionary objects?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I am trying to remove duplicates from array using for loop and conditional statement.But I am unable to create new array without any duplicates.There is xls having country name with duplicates,i am aiming to remove duplicates and create a new array with unique country names.
For e.g

```
strFilePath="D:\Country.xls"
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible=True
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open (strFilePath)
Set objSheet=objExcel.Sheets("Country")

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    objExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
    objExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
Dim A(100)
    Dim B(100)
    For i = 2 To 6 Step 1
             k = i-2
    A(k)=objSheet.Cells(i,1).Value

Next
    B(0)=A(0)
    For j = 0 To 4  Step 1
         strIt=A(j)

For m = 1 To 4 Step 1
        reslt = StrComp(A(m),strIt,1)
             If(reslt = 1 Or reslt = -1) Then
                    c=1
                    B(c)=A(m)
                    c=c+1
                    End if
                m=m+1
            Next
    Next
```

Comment: A dictionary is the simplest and most straightforward way to do this. Why would you want to make this more complicated than it has to be?

Answer (score 0):

Two options, depending on your needs:

1. Try using a hash table of the country names.   When entering values in to the hash table you could do a simultaneous check to see whether you encounter an identical value.  If it finds one it will abort entering the new value and continue with the next one, otherwise it will be entered in to the table.   At the end of it you will have your list of unique country names.
2. Sort the list of countries and then do a second pass that removes duplicate countries (since duplicates will now be grouped together)

Problems with both of these methods is that they dont preserve original order unless you keep some sort of "original index" value and then sort based on that value once you remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I usually do it:

```
Dim uniqueentries()
ReDim uniqueentries(-1)

' Here you could go through your existing array and 
' call "GetUniqueEntries" sub on each entry, e.g.
For Each i In oldarray
    GetUniqueEntries i
Next


Sub GetUniqueEntries(newentry)
    Dim entry
    If UBound(uniqueentries) >= 0 Then ' Only check if uniqieentries contains any entries
        For Each entry In uniqueentries
            If newentry = entry Then Exit Sub ' If the entry you're testing already exists in array then exit sub
        Next
    End If
    ReDim Preserve uniqueentries(UBound(uniqueentries) + 1) ' Increase new array size
    uniqueentries(UBound(uniqueentries)) = newentry ' Add unique entry to new array
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done more simpler way by using Split command. Please check the below solution, if any clarification let me know.

```
Dim aDupl
Dim aNew, strNew
aDupl = Array("A", "B", "A", "D", "C", "D")
strNew = ""
For iCnt= 0  To UBound(aDupl)
 If InStr(strNew,aDupl(iCnt) ) = 0 Then     
    strNew =strNew&aDupl(iCnt)&","
 End If
Next
aNew = Split(strNew, ",")
For iCnt=0 To UBound(aNew)
 WScript.Echo aNew(iCnt)
Next
```